# Images dynamically in iOS scrollview

Tags: ios, scrollview

I'm developing an iOS App and i'm trying to put images dynamically in a scrollview.

I declared the scrollview and i put images inside it. The images are shown in the right place, but the scrollview doesn't scroll.

This is my code:

```
imagesScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,screenWidth,screenHeight];

for (int i =0; i<dim; i++) {  //dim is the number of the images to show

NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:previewImage_URL]];
previewImages = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,10+(200*i),screenWidth,200)];

[imageView setImage:previewImages];

[imagesScrollView addSubview:imageView];

}
```

How can i do this?

Comment: You never set the content size of your scrollview, so it doesn't know that it needs to scroll.  After that you can set the userinteractions to no on the imageviews if you are still having problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to adjust the scrollview's content size to a size larger than the scrollview, so the scrollview has something to scroll to. In this case the minimal content size needed to display all of the images can be set by using:

```
[imageScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(screenWidth, 10+(200*(dim - 1)) + 200)];
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to set the content size with

```
[imageScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(100,200)];
```